# Is there an easy method of process mapping a complex SSIS package so I can print it out?

Tags: sql-server, process, ssis, mapping

I have taken ownership of a very complex SSIS package with multiple files and routes. Is there an easy method of process mapping the whole process automagically so I can print it out and understand it?

**Edit:**  Added a screenshot of an example SSIS package that I need to map.

[IMAGE 1 http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8962/examplessis.jpg](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8962/examplessis.jpg)

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have your reasons for wanting to do this, but, for me, SSIS pacakges should be largely self documenting.

Its not like a standard code module that has many lines of code, functions, and paths through, etc. The IDE is inherently visual/WYSIWYG, so I'm not entirely sure what your documentation needs are.

That said, clearly its enough of a pain for you to post here for suggestions. Is there any chance you could provide more info, even a screenshot/link to see what we're dealing with.

I certainly curious :)

Comment: I haven't got round to looking at them yet but when I do I certainly will post a screenshot if I can.

Comment: Added an example screenshot of a package. Is this something I can document?

Comment: I see what your saying. Really, I would be looking to add some documentation in yourself. This may help you understand. Rename your 'execute sql task' items appropriately. Consider adding some annotations to the control flows as well. Other than that I can't be of much help.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered. I really just need to sit down and work out each stage. Like I said this is something I have picked up from somebody else so the names are what they put on. Something for me to work on anyway! Thanks for your help James.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used either, but you could look at [SSIS Documenter](https://www.ssisdocumenter.com/) and [BI Documenter](http://www.pragmaticworks.com/products/business-intelligence/bidocumenter/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion before you spend more time looking for some outside tool, try just running the actual package step-by-stepusing some test data to see what it does. When I was passing along some large SSIS packages I wrote to other engineers that's how I explained them.